# Is it possible to display grid in Vim?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am using DrawIt plugin in Vim 7 to draw some ASCII diagrams.

This might be too much, but still—

Is there any plugin which can display a grid in background, to make the drawing easier?

Comment: I don't think it's possible without hacking the source or… making your terminal window semi transparent and placing such a grid behind.

Comment: I have not suggestions about a grid, but for drawing you may want to use `set virtualedit=all`. This will free your cursor so you can position your cursor where there is no actual character. See `:h 've'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't add anything to @David and @romainl's thoughts (I think @romainl's suggestion of using a semi-transparent window with a grid behind it is inspired!).

However, you might find it easier to visualise the cursor position by using:

```
set cursorline
set cursorcolumn
```

Of course it's not a substitute for a true grid, but it will at least let you see at a glance the alignment of the cursor.

Comment: This is brilliant. Even better than a grid, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Let me propose an implementation emulating the guiding grid using Vim
highlighting features.  The following function creates the necessary
highlighting taking two mandatory arguments and another two optional ones.
The former two are distances between horizontal and vertical lines,
correspondingly.  The latter arguments are the height and the width of the
area covered with grid (in lines and characters, correspondingly).  When these
arguments are not specified the number of lines in the buffer and the length
of the longest line in it are used.

```
function! ToggleGrid(...)
    if exists('b:grid_row_grp') || exists('b:grid_prev_cc')
        call matchdelete(b:grid_row_grp)
        let &colorcolumn = b:grid_prev_cc
        unlet b:grid_row_grp b:grid_prev_cc
        return
    endif

    let [dr, dc] = [a:1, a:2]
    if a:0 < 4
        let [i, nr, nc] = [1, line('$'), 0]
        while i <= nr
            let k = virtcol('$')
            let nc = nc < k ? k : nc
            let i += 1
        endwhile
    else
        let [nr, nc] = [a:3, a:4]
    endif
    let rows = range(dr, nr, dr)
    let cols = range(dc, nc, dc)

    let pat = '\V' . join(map(rows, '"\\%" . v:val . "l"'), '\|')
    let b:grid_row_grp = matchadd('ColorColumn', pat)
    let b:grid_prev_cc = &colorcolumn
    let &colorcolumn = join(cols, ',')
endfunction
```

Comment: I copied this to .vimrc. I get errors while calling the function:

`Error detected while processing function <SNR>19_ToggleGrid:
line    8:
E121: Undefined variable: a:1
E15: Invalid expression: [a:1, a:2]
line   19:
E121: Undefined variable: dr
.                                                                   .`

Comment: @divya:  Please specify distances between horizontal and vertical lines of the grid as arguments.  (See the updated answer.)  For example, run `:call ToggleGrid(3, 5)`.

Comment: thanks for the update. Now I am  getting the error " Unknown function: matchadd". Observed that, another plugin that I am using has some code like 'check if matchadd exists, if so use it, else use 2match'. [MarkLines Plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2028). Could you please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm inclined to agree with @romainl; I can't think of any way to do this truly in Vim without mucking around with the source. However, I can think of a few workarounds.

1. In many terminal emulators, you can set a background image. (`xfce4-terminal` has this feature, for example). You could design a background where the dimensions of each cell correspond to the space occupied by your monospace font.
2. Nate Kane's [vim-indent-guide](https://github.com/nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides) might be helpful- it displays vertical lines you could use to align characters. See the [screenshots](https://github.com/nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides#screenshots) page for some examples.
3. You could abuse Vim's highlighting to simulate a grid of sorts.